# Finding moment.js objects within an array of moments?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an array of moment() moment.js objects. The objects contain a date, and a starting time, there can be N number of objects for any given day.

I can't sort out how to search the array and return all the moments that fall within a given day. Is it possible to do this without iterating through the entire array? (around 500 objects)

```
var dateTimeList = [];
// Grabs a bunch of date\times converts them to moments, adds to array
dateTimeList.push(moment(data[i]["start_date"]  + data[i]["begintime"], "YYYYMMDDHHmm"));

 function dateSelected(someSpecificDay, dateTimeList){
       var startDate = moment(someSpecificDay);
       var endDate = startDate.endOf('day');
       var matchingMoments = [];
       // Stuck here, How can i use inArray(){} to add the moment if it falls within that particular day?
 }
```

Example inputs (formatting changed for clarity):

```
 12/31/2019 09:00
 1/1/2020 13:00
 1/1/2020 14:00
 1/1/2020 08:00
 1/3/2020 09:00
```

On Date Selected (Selected Date 1/1) return:

```
 1/1/2020 13:00
 1/1/2020 14:00
 1/1/2020 08:00
```

On Date Selected (Selected Date 1/5) return:

```
Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do this without iterating through the entire array?

No, you have to iterate through the entire array. Whatever method you use, it will iterate through the entire array under the hood.

If you want to do this without iteration, you should use a different data structure, such as object with days as keys. That would let you get the corresponding objects by `dateTimeList["1/1"]`.